# Checking for different values associated with a similar descriptor entered multiple times in a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 2 sheets in a workbook, one "Summary", the other "Enrolments". In "Enrolments" I have a list of individual entries, outlining what classes a student has enrolled in, all identified by their ID number and course code, for example:

```
     A           B

 1. ID          Course Code
 2. 123456      225.885
 3. 123456      887.112 
 4. 123456      778.560
 5. 901201      887.112
 6. 902101      555.123
 7. 987654      225.885
 8. 100001      887.112
```

In "Summary" I have a table showing the student number and a table showing each course. Like so:

```
          A        B       C           D          E



 1. .............225.885......887.112.....778.560....555.123

 2. 123456
 3. 901201
 4. 987654
 5. 100001
```

What I want to be able to do is write a script or formula to search for the Student ID in the "Summary" list, then check and see what classes the student is enrolled in in "Enrolments", then put a check in each box the student is enrolled in, in the table on the "Summary" sheet.

I have tried had formulas using nested IF and VLOOKUP to check the enrolment and also IF INDEX/MATCH nested formulas like putting this formula in each cell of the courses (i.e. B2:D5):

```
=IF(INDEX(Enrolments!$A$2:$H$10,MATCH(Summary!$A2,Enrolments!$A$2:$A$10,0))=B$1,"X"," ")
```

But every one I have tried, looks only at the first instance of the ID number in the list and not the subsequent entries. So I guess functions are not the way to go... Is there a way to use a VBA script to force the formula to repeat the function for all entries? Or another function I have not tried?

Comment: Would a PivotTable be acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Joseph's answer, however since I had worked this up, and in the event that a PivotTable (which could also be put on a separate sheet), is acceptable:

- 1) In the field list drag the ID numbers to the Row Labels,
- 2) Drag the Course Codes to the Column Labels,
- 3) Drag either the ID numbers or Course Codes to Values,
- 4) [Optional] Turn the Grand Totals off, and set Layout Report to
  Tabular Form
- 5) Change the Field Value setting to Count,
- 6) Select the entire range of values inside the PivotTable,
- 7) Format the cells using the "Select only cells that contain"
  option,
- 8) Make sure the boxes show "Cell Value", "Equal to", "1",
- 9) For Format select "Custom" and in the box marked Type type the
  letter "x",
- 10) Select "OK", "OK", and "OK".

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! All hail the mighty pivot table. I knew there would be a way.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is a MULTICOLUMN-LookUp. To perform MultiCOLUMN LookUp, you must first BUILD a searchKey column.[image]

**ENROLMENTS**

- Create ColumnB (SearchKey) which actually join the StudentID and CourseCode together. Formula is `C3 & "x" & D3`. The idea is to create a uniqueID for each Student & Course s/he took.

**SUMMARY**

- In the "Tick Section", You perform a VLookup with the `SearchKey` (StudentID + CourseID) against the `SearchKey` in **Enrolments**.
- If that SearchKey is FOUND, it means that student is enrolled for that course.
- If that SearchKey is NOT FOUND, it means the student is NOT enrolled for that course.

**Please take note of the $ in the formula, which dictates the static portion of the cell.

**Having a Formula-Based Lookup has an advantage to a pivot-table in that it has more flexibility and allow for further calculation based on the result.

Comment: Of course! A unique identifier would make it much simpler. Thank you. But I think I will keep this up my sleeve and try the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both, excellent answers, I knew you guys would have the answer. If you work on a problem for a long time, you get fixated on a single method, thanks for busting me out of my funk. Both answers worked perfectly, I used the pivot table in the end as it took about 4 clicks. Thanks again.